# How to stop code execution while waiting for Wifi and Bluetooth adapters to enable in Android?

Tags: android

I had to manually turn on the network adapters in my program, and on Android this takes a while for the hardware to power up, up to a second.

```
//turn on network adapters
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
bluetoothAdapter.enable();

while(wifiManager.getWifiState()!=WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED | bluetoothAdapter.getState!=BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON)

   ; //no code here, just waiting for adapters to enable

//continue execution
getDeviceInfo();
```

The above method I'm using now is not elegant at all, the CPU is locked-up in the while loop. Any ideas how to implement this in a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the very least, you can put that in a thread (check out `AsyncTask`) and have it Thread.sleep(10) in your while loop.

Going deeper, you can register for broadcast events so that you get notified when the wifi state changes. That way, you can react even if something outside your app changes the wifi state. Look into `BroadcastReceiver`s.

Comment: Oh yes I totally forgot about broadcast receivers. Thanks for the idea! I tried AsyncTask, but Android turns weird when I call view objects and adapters from the AsyncTask.

Comment: You're not supposed to manipulate any UI elements from within the AsyncTask thread, however it provides some hooks to make that easier. You can also use Handlers to communicate with UI threads. (btw: if you like the answer and feel it answers your question, please mark it as accepted).